# How do write a script in ksh to remove the last record in a list of records?

Tags: linux, unix, ksh

After performing some operations I am getting a set of records. Example:

```
a
b
c
```

How can I remove the last record and get all the remaining records?

Comment: You should post at least a relevant portion of your code.

Comment: Do you have a script for that? It would be useful if you posted it in order to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# cat test
a
b
c
# head -n -1 < test
a
b
```

Comment: Nice, but doesn't work with all versions of `head` (OK: GNU; not OK - MacOS X, AIX, ...).  OTOH, it does work better than `sed` when there is more than one line at the end to delete.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed '$d' <<!
a
b
c
!
```

Note that this works very portably for the specific case of 'delete last line'.  It does not work for 'delete last N lines' when N > 1; at that point, `sed` is probably not the right tool.

Using `head -n -N` works if you use GNU's version of `head` - it does not work with most other versions of `head` (AIX, MacOS X, ...).

This Perl code works - it can probably be written in Python too without much more fuss.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use constant N => 10;

my(@lines);

while (<>)
{
    print shift @lines while (scalar(@lines) >= N);
    push @lines, $_;
}
```

Exercise for the reader: upgrade the code to handle command line options specifying the value of N instead of hard-coding it at 10.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best script in the world, but here it goes:

`Usage: script_name.sh {original_file} {copy_file}`

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
  echo "Usage: $0 {original_file} {copy_file}"
  exit $E_BADARGS
fi

lines=`wc -l $1`
num_lines=`echo ${lines:0:1}`

if [ $num_lines -ne 0 ]
then
    last_line=${num_lines-1}
    sed "${last_line}d" < $1 > $2
else
    echo "The file is empty!"
fi

exit 0
```